# I Have A Problem In Laravel File Upload. How To Get Original Uploaded File?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Upload MS Word Document (.docx) in Laravel Using `<input type="file">`

My MS Word File is Automatically Converted as (.file) Format While Storing in storage/app/public

How to Again Download Same (.docx) Formatted File?

**ApplicationController.php**

```
function create(Request $req)
    {
        $application = new Application;
        $application->opening_id = $req->input('opening_id');
        $application->first_name = $req->input('first_name');
        $application->last_name = $req->input('last_name');
        $application->gender = $req->input('gender');
        $application->dob = $req->input('dob');
        $application->address = $req->input('address');
        $application->mobile = $req->input('mobile');
        $application->email = $req->input('email');
        $path = $req->file('resume')->store('public/resumes');
        $path = trim($path,"public/");
        $application->resume = $path;
        $application->application_status = $req->input('application_status');
        $application->save();
        return redirect('admin/view-applications');
    }
```

**Add-Application.php**

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="custom-file">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="resume" required>
<label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose Resume</label>
</div>
```

[Image: Saved File Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5CGY.png)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not run a debugger and check where this strange conversion occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your saving part and it'll work.
You need to extract original name of file which and pass it to `store` method which will prevent the `store` method from giving it automatic name, Try the below code and let me know

```
function create(Request $req){
    $application = new Application;
    $application->opening_id = $req->input('opening_id');
    $application->first_name = $req->input('first_name');
    $application->last_name = $req->input('last_name');
    $application->gender = $req->input('gender');
    $application->dob = $req->input('dob');
    $application->address = $req->input('address');
    $application->mobile = $req->input('mobile');
    $application->email = $req->input('email');
    $filename = $req->file('resume')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $req->file('resume')->storeAs('public/resumes',$fileName);
    $path = trim($path,"public/");
    $application->resume = $path;
    $application->application_status = $req->input('application_status');
    $application->save();
    return redirect('admin/view-applications');
}
```